# Wordpress Menu for current Custom Post Type

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, custom-post-type

I am looking to automatically create a Wordpress Menu for the 'current' Custom Post Type. I found a useful snippet that outputs the current custom post type here:-

```
 $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID );
 echo $post_type;
```

But am struggling to translate this (or alternate method) into a dynamically created menu for the current custom post type - list all posts in the custom post type. I can't do this on an individual custom post type basis as I'm using a master template to display a series of custom post types.

Thanks

Glennyboy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a super simple way to do it.  just create a loop that lists all the page titles wrapped in a link.

```
<?php 
    $obj = get_post_type_object(get_post_type($post->ID));
    echo '<h2>' .  $obj->labels->name . '</h2>';
?>
<ul>
    <?php 
        $query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => get_post_type($post->ID), 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date',));
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();    
    ?>

        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>  

    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

This will loop through all the current post's post type and create an unordered list with all the posts titles, wrapped in links to the posts.  You could obviously change the HTML to suit your needs.

Comment: Wonderful! How could I add the Custom Post Type name/itle to the above as h2?

Comment: Do you mean the CPT name or the post title links?

Comment: The CPT name as heading

Comment: Just put it above the opening `<ul>`.  I'll make a quick edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out on this one Andy. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Andy. How could I update the above so that it also takes the current post and then shows the next 3 posts with title as before. I'm tying to achieve this through a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361996/wordpress-show-next-3-x-number-adjacent-custom-posts-from-existing

Comment: I think I got this squared away, I'll post an answer to your question.