# Wordpress show next 3 x number adjacent custom posts from existing

Tags: wordpress, pagination, navigation, custom-post-type, show

On a single/detail Custom Post Page I would like to display a custom nav of li's or divs in a sidebar that displays both title, excerpt and permalink for the next 3 posts within the custom post series. So if we are on custom post 3 then it would show 4, 5, 6 in the sidebar.

The closest I've found to this is :-=

```
global $post;
$current_post = $post; // remember the current post

for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++){
 $post = get_previous_post(); // this uses $post->ID
setup_postdata($post);

// do your stuff here       
the_title();

}

$post = $current_post; // restore
```

Problem is this only shows the first next post and I need to show 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code from above is very close.  It looks like you're just missing an `endfor;` and maybe a bit of html.  Try the blow code:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        global $post;
        $current_post = $post;

        for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++):
        $post = get_previous_post();
        setup_postdata($post);

        echo '<li>';
        echo '<h3>' . get_the_title() . '</h3>';
        the_excerpt();
        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_metafield_name', true);
        echo '</li>';

        endfor;
        $post = $current_post; 

    ?>
</ul>
```

When using `the_excerpt()` it should include a "read more" link already to the post, so you won't need to use `the_permalink()` function.  If you don't have 3 or more previous posts, it will only show how many previous posts there are.  I tested this in the single.php template file, but it should work in a custom post type single template file if you are using a custom one.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: that does indeed work. problem  I now find is that is this is not a Wordpress Query / Loop that I can't  output my custom fields. Is there any way to update the above so that it is a Wordpress Query?

Comment: As noted this does work Andy and I also got round the issue with the Custom Fields. If this can be achieved as a Wordpress Custom Query that would be very interesting, but for now this is the only way I've seen this actually workings as required. Thanks Andy

Comment: You can use `echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_metafield_name', true);` to render custom metafields.

Comment: I'll edit my answer above.  Just change the `'your_meta_field'` to the name of the one you want to render.  I tested and it is working.

Comment: Andy how can I extend the above to automatically create a link that goes back to the custom post archive page with the custom post name (and including the theme slug). I've amended the above so that a new li is displayed after the last item (rather than 3 blank boxes) that should link back to the main custom post page / archive.

Comment: Create a new question and then link it here:  I have the code ready.

Comment: I achieved this with $site_url = get_site_url();

Comment: Andy if you have an alternate way please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410175/automatically-create-a-link-that-goes-back-to-the-custom-post-archive-page-with

Comment: New question is answered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that get_previous_post() gets the post previous to the current post, so your for loop just gets the same post 3 times.

What you need to use is [wp_get_recent_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts). You would use it inside the WordPress loop, using a [secondary loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Secondary_Loops) to make that query.

Depending on where you're adding the code, you might just be able to use wp_get_recent_posts():

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post');

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );
```

Comment: would you be able to provide an example of how to implement the above?

Comment: Or a better way to do it?