# Automatically create a link that goes back to the custom post archive page with the custom post name (and including the theme slug)

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, custom-post-type

How can I automatically create a link that goes back to the current custom post archive page with the custom post name (and including the theme slug)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick way to do it.  You can post this in your single post template files.  It will check for the post type, determine if the main blog is on the homepage of the site, or determine if the main blog is on a secondary page, and display the appropriate links.

```
<?php
    // Get the current post type
    $postType = get_post_type();

    // Check if post type is "post" and if main blog is the home page
    if ($postType == post && get_option('show_on_front') == 'page') {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink(get_option('page_for_posts')) . '">Main Blog Archive Link</a>';
    // Check is post type is "post" and not set to have main blog on home page
    } elseif ($postType == post && !get_option('show_on_front') == 'page') {
        echo '<a href="' . site_url() . '">Front Page Index Link</a>';
    // If custom post type do this
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . get_post_type_archive_link($postType) . '">Post Type Archive Link</a>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: ... although the generated link seems to go to the current post link rather than /theme/custom-post-archive/

Comment: Yes, this will get the post type of the current post and generate a link to that post's archive page.  It will work for the regular "posts" as well as any custom post type.  What were you looking for?

Comment: That's great, but I just want a link to the current parent custom post. For example if the slug is 'site/theme/my-custom-post/the-custom-post' then I just want to show a link back to the parent 'site/theme/my-custom-post/'

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you're asking for.  I think you want to go back to the parent post type, which the code above will do.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'll try it again - the link before just went to the current post for the custom post type